# How to create a horizontal menu in Jekyll?

Tags: navigation, jekyll

I have a simple blog with posts in Jekyll.

I would like to transfer my posts into pages and have a horizontal menu like you have in Wordpress.

What is the canonical way in Jekyll to do this?

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/navigation/

Answer (score 1):

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/:

Creating an index of posts on another page should be easy thanks to Liquid and its tags. Here’s a simple example of how to create a list of links to your blog posts:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The page contains more information on how to deal with post pages/templates.